# Parsing xml and after each node notifying class that called for method

Tags: java, xml

I'm looking for best way to notify my class that creates and instance of xml parser about each parsed line of code.

I would like to update gui etc. after each line obtained from the parser before it reads the next line and so on, what would be the best way to achieve this? Make xmlparser an observer?

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
       public Controller(){
             XMLParser parser = new XMLParser():
             parser.parseDocument() //Get value after each loop
       }
}
```

**XMLParser.java**

```
public class XMLParser {

   String type="", value="";

    public void parseDocument() throws Exception{
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("gaugeInput.xml");
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
        streamReader.nextTag(); // Advance to "gauge_input" element
        streamReader.nextTag(); // Advance to "gauge" element

        while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
            if (streamReader.isStartElement()) {
                switch (streamReader.getLocalName()) {
                    case "type": {
                        type = streamReader.getElementText();
                        break;
                    }
                    case "value": {
                        value = streamReader.getElementText();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(streamReader.isEndElement()){
                System.out.println("Package for controller: type: "+type+" value: "+value);
            }
            streamReader.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a "listener" to the `parseDocument` method. The listener would be an interface which has a method which can be called after each tag. The `Controller` class can implement the listener to get notified.

This should work with code that looks something like this:

```
public interface TagListener {
    void onTagRead(<parameters>);
}

public class Controller implements TagListener {
   public Controller(){
         XMLParser parser = new XMLParser():
         parser.parseDocument(this) // pass the controller instance to get notified
   }

   public void onTagRead(<parameter>) {
        // your logic :)
   }
}

public class XMLParser {

     String type="", value="";

     public void parseDocument(TagListener listener) throws Exception{
          XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
          InputStream in = new FileInputStream("gaugeInput.xml");
          XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
          streamReader.nextTag(); // Advance to "gauge_input" element
          streamReader.nextTag(); // Advance to "gauge" element

          while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
               if (streamReader.isStartElement()) {
                   switch (streamReader.getLocalName()) {
                        case "type": {
                           type = streamReader.getElementText();
                           break;
                        }
                        case "value": {
                           value = streamReader.getElementText();
                           break;
                        }
                   }
               }
               else if(streamReader.isEndElement()){
                   listener.onTagRead(...);
               }
               streamReader.next();
         }
    }
}
```